# Problems with space character in Bash cut command when using a different delimiter

Tags: bash, delimiter, cut, shell

I have set | to be the delimiter for a `cut` command, but space characters seem to still be interpreted as a delimiter too.

Here's my test script:

```
people[1]="Mr|Smith"
people[2]="Mrs|Jane Brown"

for person in ${people[@]}
do
    title=$(echo $person | cut -f1 -d\|)
    name=$(echo $person | cut -f2 -d\|)
    echo $title $name
    echo
done
```

Which outputs:

```
Mr Smith

Mrs Jane

Brown Brown
```

Can anyone shed some light on why the space character in Jane Brown is causing problems?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose `${people[@]}` in double quotes:

```
for person in "${people[@]}"
...
```

Otherwise, `Mrs|Jane Brown` will get interpreted as 2 separate tokens: `Mrs|Jane` and `Brown`.

Think of it as:

```
for i in "a b c"; do echo $i; done # echoes "a b c" just once
```

versus

```
for i in a b c; do echo $i; done # does an echo for a, b and c
```